# Would paint or stain last longer on 15 yr old, badly weathered cedar fascia

Tags: stain, oil, cedar, base

Preparing to move into 15 yr old home that has (4) 12/12 & 14/12 Aesthetic gables in the front of house.
The gables were initially stained with a dark stain, & are VERY BADLEY  weather worn with only traces of the Stain barely visible. About (90-95)% is bare wood, not kidding !!!

Kinda like the stain disintegrated / evaporated off the board leaving a grey silver tone. But the boards seem to be in good shape with no rot or damage visible.
The highest gable is 22 ft high with the other 3 gables at 16-18 ft high. The rest of house is hip roof, with engineered fascia, so no issues there.

QUESTION: what would be the best treatment, STAIN a PAINTED STAIN or OIL BASE PRIMER & that will last longer & out-live me?

Comment: Stain penetrates the wood, so it lasts longer

Comment: Be sure to do _thorough_ surface prep or it won't matter. Also, be sure it's actually stain that's left - stain won't do any good over paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience (45 Years), a high quality stain would be best. I can recommend and excellent one: DEFY EXTREME WOOD STAIN. It is UV resistant and can be tinted any color. Look up the test results on it - it ranks at the top. I have it on my deck and house trim and it is still in excellent shape after many years of exposure to direct sun and rain and snow.

Comment: Kennydeee  FreeMan I did research the (DEFFY EXREME) water base wood stain & it’s reviews were very impressive. 
     Since you have 45 yrs of applying top coats, can you tell me your ( good or bad experience ) using (oil base primer & latex top coats) to cover very aged & warn Cedar with only about 10 to 15% of the initial stain job remaining.

Comment: FreeMan suggested I should throughly prep the Cedar ( & I agree ),  but due to my age & physical condition, about the best prep is going to be ( Hard Brushing ) to wipe the stain/paint onto the wood & would you except to see much peeling if a oil based primer was used.
    I’m sure the stain would not peel, but may disinigrate like these cedar boards are showing now, with only about 10 to 15 % of the original covering remaining after 15 yrs of wind, rain & sun abuse

Comment: Man, I wish we had more than 5 minutes to edit comments, I so old & decrepit & worn out from 40 yrs on drilling rigs, it’s really hard for me to comment.

Comment: Oily Tex, I still recommend the Defy stain. Paint, whether oil base primer or latex primer, is still, in my opinion, less flexible than stain, which causes it to be more susceptible to to cracking and admitting moisture. The critical measure here is how UV resistant your application is and how much penetration you can achieve with your application.

Answer (score 1):

Paint and stain are different products. They are similar in that they both have pigments. Stains are not meant to totally obscure the surface. Leaving the wood grain visible. Paint is meant to totally cover up the surface with a much thicker layer of protection. However, if the paint is not really adhered well, it can peel off easily.

Stains usually have more penetration into the wood with preservatives. Once wood is painted, it’s difficult to stain and make look uniform.